# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am writing an application using Hibernate and Spring. However I am encountering the following error:

```
nov. 11, 2011 10:32:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Infos: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;.
nov. 11, 2011 10:32:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Infos: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
nov. 11, 2011 10:32:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Infos: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
nov. 11, 2011 10:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Infos: Initialization processed in 769 ms
nov. 11, 2011 10:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Infos: Démarrage du service Catalina
nov. 11, 2011 10:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Infos: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.21
nov. 11, 2011 10:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
Infos: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration achrefliferay-portlet.xml
nov. 11, 2011 10:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
Avertissement: A docBase C:\liferay-portal-6.1.0\tomcat-7.0.21\webapps\achrefliferay-portlet inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
nov. 11, 2011 10:32:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
Avertissement: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:achrefliferay-portlet' did not find a matching property.
10:32:13,318 INFO  [ContextLoader:187] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
10:32:13,367 INFO  [XmlWebApplicationContext:456] Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Nov 11 10:32:13 GMT 2011]; root of context hierarchy
10:32:13,446 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
10:32:13,705 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml]
10:32:14,198 INFO  [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer:177] Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties]
10:32:14,286 INFO  [DefaultListableBeanFactory:422] Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2d726d05: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,articleDaoImp,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource#0,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,txnManager,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
10:32:14,305 ERROR [ContextLoader:220] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/LobHandler;
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] for bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/LobHandler;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.LobHandler
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    ... 39 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1242)
    ... 30 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] for bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1242)
    ... 30 more
nov. 11, 2011 10:32:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Error listenerStart
nov. 11, 2011 10:32:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Erreur de démarrage du contexte [/achrefliferay-portlet] suite aux erreurs précédentes
nov. 11, 2011 10:32:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
Infos: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration ROOT.xml
Loading jar:file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.0/tomcat-7.0.21/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
10:32:15,617 INFO  [EasyConf:122] Refreshed the configuration of all components
10:32:15,959 INFO  [ConfigurationLoader:56] Properties for jar:file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.0/tomcat-7.0.21/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal loaded from [file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.0/tomcat-7.0.21/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-developer.properties, file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.0/portal-ide.properties, file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.0/tomcat-7.0.21/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties, jar:file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.0/tomcat-7.0.21/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties]
Loading jar:file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.0/tomcat-7.0.21/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
Loading file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.0/tomcat-7.0.21/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
Loading file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.0/portal-ide.properties
Loading file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.0/tomcat-7.0.21/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-developer.properties
10:32:22,625 INFO  [DialectDetector:80] Determine dialect for PostgreSQL 9
10:32:22,678 INFO  [DialectDetector:145] Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Starting Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.0 CE (Paton / Build 6100 / March 24, 2011)
10:32:47,529 INFO  [BaseDB:406] Database supports case sensitive queries
10:32:48,000 INFO  [PluginPackageUtil:1098] Reading plugin package for the root context
10:32:54,200 INFO  [PluginPackageUtil:1282] Reloading repositories
10:32:59,742 INFO  [AutoDeployDir:105] Auto deploy scanner started for C:\liferay-portal-6.1.0\deploy
10:33:01,108 INFO  [PluginPackageUtil:1101] Reading plugin package for achrefliferay-portlet
10:33:01,109 WARN  [PluginPackageUtil:1060] Plugin package on context achrefliferay-portlet cannot be tracked because this WAR does not contain a liferay-plugin-package.xml file
nov. 11, 2011 10:33:01 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader findResourceInternal
Infos: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load service.properties.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
nov. 11, 2011 10:33:01 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader findResourceInternal
Infos: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load service.properties.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
nov. 11, 2011 10:33:01 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader findResourceInternal
Infos: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load portlet.properties.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
nov. 11, 2011 10:33:01 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader findResourceInternal
Infos: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load portlet.properties.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
nov. 11, 2011 10:33:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
Infos: Déploiement du répertoire tunnel-web de l'application web
nov. 11, 2011 10:33:08 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Infos: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
nov. 11, 2011 10:33:08 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Infos: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
nov. 11, 2011 10:33:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Infos: Server startup in 55882 ms
```

### hibernatedataaccess.xml

This is my `hibernatedataaccess.xml`:

```xml
      <!-- Auto-detect the DAOs -->
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.bd.dao"/>

      <context:property-placeholder location="WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>


        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
            <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
            <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        </bean>



        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>com.bd.entity.Article</value>

                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>     
                    <!-- generation base donnée     <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                </props>
            </property>

        </bean>



      <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txnManager"/>

      <bean id="txnManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
            p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>

      <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    </beans>
```

### aplicationcontest.xml

This is my `aplicationcontest.xml`:

```xml
  <!-- Auto-detect components -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.bd.entity"/> 
<b:import resource="hibernateDataAccessContext.xml"/>

</b:beans>
```

### Web.xml

This is my `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>achrefliferay-portlet</display-name>

   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>

                        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

        </param-value>
    </context-param>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

  <context-param>
        <description>
        Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Vaadin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>
            Vaadin application class to start</description>
            <param-name>application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.vaadin.demo.workoutlog.WorkoutLog</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Vaadin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Vaadin-hibernate-portletApplicationServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Vaadin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>
            /WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld
        </taglib-location>
    </taglib>
  </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: maybe you should have posted the pom.xml as well. there could be a problem with the Spring dependency. So make sure Spring jar will be on classpath when you run it.

Answer (score 19):

Make sure archive `org.springframework.jdbc_XX.jar` exists in your classpath.

Answer (score 13):

insert this dependency to your pom.xml file:

It will run properly definitely!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Saved me. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, I added [spring-jdbc 3.2.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.2.0.RELEASE) in my classpath.
Thank you.